# Passing sensitive parameters in report URL

Tags: jasperserver

I need to hide the sensitive information when sending parameter in my Jasper report, like username, password, database name, IDs …etc.

so far I have been using GET method to print the report i want, like this :

```
http://192.168.13.198/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2FMY_DATABASE&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Ffinance_dsc%2FMY_REPORT&standAlone=true&j_username=joeuser&j_password=joeuser&output=pdf&ID=9999
```

but, since I'm still new to jasper I don't know how to hide them.

Comment: Why you are needed to pass the sensitive information as request param. Make this query inside controller

Comment: Use POST, then the parameters are in the request body. This is rather trivial.

Comment: @user207421: But a password in the post body is also not safe..... 